# Yahoo weather Api (RSS) is not working

Tags: xml, rss, yql

I am using webscript.io to get the weather information using the YQL but now it does not return the actual XML values, which it should. I was using the ZIP Code (02215) mentioned in the link to get the specific location weather report in XML form.

https://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=02215

It gives this error!

```
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" xml:lang="en-US" yahoo:uri="http://yahoo.com">
<yahoo:description>
Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR", realm="yahooapis.com"
</yahoo:description>
<yahoo:detail>
Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR", realm="yahooapis.com"
</yahoo:detail>
</yahoo:error>
```

I am sure I am reading it right as per this link

https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/archive.html

Comment: what part of `Please provide valid credentials` is not clear?

Comment: @Lashane Thank you for your valuable feedback !! I also do understand the statement but when I check 
[oauth link] (https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/) which clearly say that **If you are using YQL or other Yahoo APIs, please refer to OAuth 1 guide.**

and also provides the link to the **OAuth 1** which just returns back "_An internal error occurred (eid 3964028)._"

I hope that helps to understand the thing

Comment: any update with this problem? I am also facing same in finance api

Comment: Any one with the solution.